# Why can't I access a specific Key within my Dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, api, dictionary, key-value

I've tried breaking this down as best I can.

Here is the relevant code with my best explanation of what each line does.

```
public static string DetailCall()
        {
            //Call original API POST Method to get Data
            string data = BlocCall();
            //Clean Data by removing extra characters
            var charsToRemove = new string[] { "{", "\"", " "};
            foreach (var c in charsToRemove)
            {
                data = data.Replace(c, string.Empty);
            }

            //Split string of data into an array of data by individual
            string[] guys = data.Split('}');
            
            //Do stuff with each persons data
            foreach (var individual in guys)
            {   
                //Split Data into key value pairs and add to Dictionary
                var uDict = individual.Split(',').Select(part => part.Split(':')).Where(part => part.Length == 2).ToDictionary(sp => sp[0], sp => sp[1]);

                //Turn the Dictionary back into a string for testing purposes
                var s_uDict = String.Join(",", uDict.Select(kvp => String.Format("{0}={1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value)));

     
                Trace.WriteLine(s_uDict);

                Trace.WriteLine("Exist key " + uDict.ContainsKey("INDIVIDUALID"));     

            }
         }
```

I've used Trace.WriteLine to do some debugging and this is the (*changed for hippa reasons*) output in the console. It shows the contents of the dictionary as a string and I can clearly see which keys and values exist.

individualID=-----,
firstName=------,
middleInitial=,
lastName=------,
email=------@gmail.com,
ssn=,
status=01.FreshLead,
type=,
homePhone=(---)--------,
businessPhone=,
cellPhone=

Exist key False

But whenever I try to access the data using

```
var cliID = uDict["individualID"];
```

I get the error that the Key "individualID" does not exist even though I can see in the output that it does??

I've also tried with the other key values and get the same result.

I'm pretty stumped at this point, and hope anyone can help me figure this out.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you show your string data pls?

Comment: @Serge if OP shows sample data it would not be acceptable to answer the question as asked - if you look at the cleanup part of the code you can see that original data was JSON and all structure is stripped with `string.Replace`. This would endup in similar comment storm as if one tries to parse HTML with RegEx... (Also it would be nice if OP actually provided [MCVE] with data inline)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dictionary contains:

> individualID=-----,

Your lookup that attempt seems to be:

> `Trace.WriteLine("Exist key " + uDict.ContainsKey("INDIVIDUALID"));`

> Exist key False

`"INDIVIDUALID"` will have a completely different hashcode to `"individualID"`; in short - dictionary keys are case sensitive

Elsewhere in the post you indicated that you're looking up `uDict["individualID"]` which *is* correctly cased; if you're truly getting that I'd hazard a guess that it isn't the `uDict` you think it is e.g. you've got a clas level `uDict` variable and a local one named the same and you're getting them confused, etc

I had a go at reconstructing your input string and the code appears fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nNy8ar

Alexei's comment is wise too; you appear to be rolling your own JSON parser. Don't bother; you can get Newtonsoft.Json (free, use Nuget Package Manager to install it) to give you a dictionary without all this finagling:

```
string data = BlocCall(); //e.g. { "individualID":"hello", ... }
var d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,object>>(data);

Console.WriteLine(d["individualID"]); //hello
```

Of course the real power of a json deser library like NSJ is you can get it to give you *proper object instances*:

```
public class Thing{
  [JsonProperty("individualID")]
  public string IndividualId {get; set;}
}

string data = BlocCall(); //e.g. { "individualID":"hello", ... }
var w = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Thing>(data);

Console.WriteLine(w.IndividualId); //hello
```

Much nicer than all that stringly typed nonsense :)

Comment: Wow this is great. The capitalization was just a test, I'd tried all the different cases.
Will the deserializer work within the foreach loop? the  string[] guys = data.Split('}') is to separate the mutliple "individuals" within the data, and I want to do some other things foreach individual if that makes sense.
I'll give it a shot now either way.

Comment: So, it didn't work the way I understood it too. Also the API response from BlocCall() is not a JSON. It's a  Text/HTML response read as string...

Comment: Can you show the actual full string you get from  BlocCall?

Comment: [
{
    "individualID": ####,
    "firstName": "ABCD",
    "middleInitial": "",
    "lastName": "EFGH",
    "email": "",
   ...
  },
  {
    "individualID": ######,
    "firstName": "ABCD",
    "middleInitial": "",
    "lastName": "EFGH",
    "email": "ABCDEFGH@gmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1955-05-10T00:00:00",
    "ssn": "",
    "status": "01. Fresh Lead",
    ...
  }
]
this is what Trace.WriteLine(data): looks like

Comment: Sure looks like JSON to me .. paste it into http://QuickType.io to generate a bunch of c# classes (like that one I put in the answer `class Thing` only more full), helpers for deser'ing and even a comment block telling you how to use it

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out. BlocCall is a public static string, does that make a difference whether or not the return is a JSON?

Comment: Technically BlocCall is a method that returns a string. Static just defines what kind of contexts it is available in. It is the content of the string that is important in determining whether the string is JSON or not, rather than the attributes of the method that generates it.

Comment: Ok, I tried the second suggestion and am getting an error:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'SFFDataEntry.APIHelper+Thing' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
So since it is an array of jsons it's having a problem?

Comment: Massively depends on what you've told it to do. If the json you have put in is an array of Thing then you have to `DeserializeObject<Thing[]>` rather than `<Thing>` like I pir in the answer (it was written at a time when the json was unknown) .. ? Do the QuickType thing; it's pain free, cost free and takes seconds. And it'll be right for the json you paste in

Comment: using QuickType.io generated a huge block of code that I wasn't able to figure out. I'm sorry, but I may just have to find a different work around for this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You put all the code it generates in one file and you read the comment at the top; it's only one line you need to call. You don't really need to understand the rest of the code, but it's mainly just classes that hold data

Comment: Ok, but I'm still not sure how to access the Individual id? I use Trace.WriteLine(welcome.IndividualId); and it is throwing an exception because IndividualID doesn't exist?? and i don't know how to use a foreach to perform the actions I need to on each individual this way?

Comment: public static string DetailCall()

        {
            
            //Call original API POST Method to get Data

            string data = BlocCall();

      
            var welcome = Welcome.FromJson(data);
            
            foreach (var individual in welcome)
            {
                var CliID = welcome.IndividualId;
            }

It says: Welcome[] does not contain a definition for IndividualId

Comment: Your messages seem confused. Welcome is the default class name, I guess you didn't change it.. so you pasted your json in and your json started with [ meaning it's an array. So your FromJson method returns an array.. this means it seems your second code (with the foreach) is reasonable except you've said `foreach(var individual in welcome)` and that's good... but then inside the loop you said `welcome.IndividualId` but `welcome` is an array of Welcome... the variable that is each single Welcome inside the array is `individual`. Perhaps you should starts by calling your things decent names

Comment: for example in QuickType change it so it doesn't say "Welcome" at the top of the screen but instead says "Individual" or "Person" or something sensibly related to what the data is. Then when you're desering, say `var people = Person.FromJson(data)` and `foreach(var person in people) Trace.WriteLine(person.IndividualId);` calling things bad names is the best way to make code incomprehensible (google "obfuscation")

Comment: Aah you're right. I've been at this too long today

Comment: It worked! You are a saint, sir!

Comment:  yep, I get those days too.. 10h+ of coding (what a light-weight) and I reach a point where I can't see the wood for the trees; I sleep on it and the next day I'm like "well this is easy, WTH was the problem last night?" - sometimes it just ain't worth staying at it the extra half hour; rest and crash through it in ten mins saves more time ultimately ;) but glad you got there- one day it'll seem so natural..